# git: creating remote branch failed

Tags: linux, git

I tried creating remote branch `devel` using:

```
git push origin origin:refs/heads/devel
```

But it fails with:

```
error: src refspec devel does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@***.com:***/abcd.git'
```

What's going on?

EDIT:
I am following: [This Tutorial](http://www.zorched.net/2008/04/14/start-a-new-branch-on-your-remote-git-repository/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If devel is your local branch, then this is sufficient:

```
git push origin devel
```

Your example doesn't work, because you try to push "origin" branch to remote repository ("origin"), but you don't have branch named "origin" (first origin here) in local repository.

You can run:

```
git push origin devel:refs/heads/devel
#               ^     ^
#               |     +---- it's ref for remote branch to create
#               +---------- it's local branch name
```

This second form is preferred if you local branch name should differ from remote branch name.

Comment: You can be even on detached head, it doesn't matter as long as you specify source branch (second argument)

Comment: BTW that seems to be reverse. Actually I did this: `git push origin master:refs/heads/devel` which pushed `local master branch` to `remote devel branch`

Comment: @ssapkota You're right, thanks. I updated my answer. It's also described in manual for git-push, I checked to be sure, and it's described as you stated

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to do `git add` to all of your files first. Then `git commit` then `git push`?

Comment: Its actually uptodate with `master` branch. So nothing to add/commit and nothing to push.

Comment: Try `git push origin master:refs/heads/devel`. Took it from here:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html